# Buttons position gets change in custom slider in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have this custom slider

> Working Link :
> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rwuxjd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Slider is working but Next and previous buttons are not at proper location when we slide it to next or previous slides, Every slide will have different contents and slide height will also change, but issue is when i slide to next or previous then Next and Previous buttons location should be managed automatically but presently when we click on next next while slides are being translated the button moves to top most position.  I don't want to fix the button position, It should be managed according to the content height.

Any solution is highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some CSS rules for that. Try put a container div around the buttons and the image slider and give it a min-height.

Not perfect but will put you in the right direction.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-airvm5?file=src/app/app.component.css

Comment: Thanks for the answer Is there any other way to achieve it without fixing the `height` because if i fix it with `mix-height` then the content will not look some page might have less content some page can have content which can cover whole page